# how to foreach an array or object in javascript

Tags: javascript

helo i have a trouble when foreach a array or object, please help me, are array and object is different step to foreach :

```
function fetching() {

    fetch("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics", {

        "method": "GET",

        "headers": {

            "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",

            "x-rapidapi-key": "c44a47562cmsh6ff0d107514bccfp146d00jsn876b11317ac5"

        }

    })

    .then(res => res.json())

    .then(res => res.response)

    .then(cc => {

        cc.foreach(c => console.log(c))

    })

}

fetching()
```

result in console :

```
app.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cc.foreach is not a function
```

thanks .

Comment: Programming is often case-sensitive. If that's an array, the proper spelling is `forEach`

Comment: if `cc` is an array, then your `foreach` is mispelled. It needs to be camel-cased, `forEach`

Comment: god, thanks, but how to get result and foreach in outside funcing fetching ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check this solution.

```js
async function fetching() {

    const data = await fetch("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics", {

        "method": "GET",

        "headers": {

            "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",

            "x-rapidapi-key": "c44a47562cmsh6ff0d107514bccfp146d00jsn876b11317ac5"

        }

    })
  const res = await data.json();
  return res.response;
}


(async() => {
  const data = await fetching();
  // Now you can loop over the data
  console.log(data);
})()
```

Comment: thanks, but how to foreach in outside like :
`
function fetching() {
    return fetch("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "c44a47562cmsh6ff0d107514bccfp146d00jsn876b11317ac5"
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => res.response)
}
const a = fetching()
a.forEach(e => console.log(e))
`

Comment: I've edited the answer, please check now.